# Cursor in Procedure does not return any values

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor, procedure

I have a database where temp tables are created, those table names are randomly generated and saved in Checkouts.unid. I want to drop all those tables and truncate the table Checkouts. I thought the niftiest solution would be a procedure, but it will not work:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spCheckoutsCleanup`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `spCheckoutsCleanup` ()
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE `t` VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE `ch` CURSOR FOR SELECT `unid` FROM `Checkouts`;
    OPEN `ch`;

    drop_tables: LOOP
        FETCH `ch` INTO `t`;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE `ch`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `Checkouts`;
END
```

I always get "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed" although those tables are there and the table Checkouts is not empty though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something like this in order to end your loop:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ...;
```

See example in the [documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html). E.g. ...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spCheckoutsCleanup`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `spCheckoutsCleanup` ()
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE `t` VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE `ch` CURSOR FOR SELECT `unid` FROM `Checkouts`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN `ch`;

    drop_tables: LOOP
        FETCH `ch` INTO `t`;
        IF done THEN
           LEAVE drop_tables;
        END IF;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE `ch`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `Checkouts`;
END
```

Otherwise you will get an error once you reached the end of your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spCheckoutsCleanup`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `spCheckoutsCleanup` ()
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE t CHAR(64);
    DECLARE ch CURSOR FOR SELECT `unid` FROM `Checkouts`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN ch;

    drop_table: LOOP
        FETCH ch INTO t;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE drop_table;
        END IF;
        SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `', t, '`'); 
        PREPARE dropt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE dropt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE ch;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `Checkouts`;
END;
CALL spCheckoutsCleanup;
```